# How to identify the original Exception of a COMException

Tags: c#, delphi, exception, com, interop

We have an C#-written Web Application that communicates with an Delphi-written Application via COM. The C# Application invokes Methods of the Delphi Application to get the required data. An `COMException` will be thrown in our C#-Code when anything went wrong in the Delphi Application.

Here are the details of the `COMException`:

[image]

Problem: We want to handle these Exceptions dependent on the type of the Delphi-Exception. But we cannot, because it is an COMException every time.

Question: How can we identify or map the originally type of the Delphi Exception in our C#-Code?

Comment: A better design would be to return the original exception as a strong and handle it in Delphi, are you able to edit the Delphi code?

Comment: We do not want to handle it in Delphi. We want to handle it on C#-Side.

Comment: @JeremyThompson is right. Do not let exceptions escape an app or DLL into an executable written in a different language. Obviously C# can somehow handle the Delphi exceptions, but obviously the original data gets (mainly) lost. Don't do that. Handle the exceptions in Delphi, if you can, and pass the information about the kind of exception and the message in some other way.

Comment: @Rudy Velthiuis: Thank you very much for your anwer. Regarding 'pass the information about the kind of exception and the message in some other way': What is a good common way to pass the information?

Comment: The common way used in most APIs is something like a HRESULT, or some other error value. Just choose the most appropriate existing one, or define your own. You can also expose a function that returns the message to a certain error number, if you want.

Comment: Perhaps you can call Win32 `GetErrorInfo` API and then access unmanaged `ISupportErrorInfo` object for raw Delphi exception info.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR method to achieve this goal. 
It could be enhanced by custom HR codes results if needed.

Here is sample code:

```
    try
    {
        ...
    }
    catch (COMException exception)
    {
        switch (exception.HResult)
        {
            case -2147418113:
                throw new MissingFolderException("Custom exception");
        }

        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(exception.HResult);
    }
```

MissingFolderException is of course specific exception implemented in your code.

Some more details are here: [How to: Map HRESULTs and Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ztbc5s1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Can happen Delphi code doesn't return distinct exceptions in some scenarios (HResult is same for 2 different exceptions), but then the Delphi code must be modified.